# range on int, short and other data types in C on my processor?

Tags: c, variables, size, range

I was reading a old C book and according to that

int range values from -32768 to +32767.

where as my machine can hold a larger int than that limit how can I find the range of these data types(short, int, long, double, float) specific to my machine?

are there any methods for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/), take a look at the footnote:

- the actual value depends on the particular system and library implementation, but shall reflect the limits of these types in the target platform.

If you run the following code on your system, it should shed some insight because the value returned may or may not differ from the ones in the above link.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <float.h>
    #include <limits.h>

    int main() {
        printf("\t\tUsing <limits.h> library definitions...\n");
        printf("CHAR\n");
        printf("signed char max: %d\n", SCHAR_MAX);
        printf("unsigned char max: %u\n", UCHAR_MAX); // Note use of u, formatting output
        printf("signed char min: %d\n", SCHAR_MIN);
        printf("SHORT\n");
        printf("signed short min: %d\n", SHRT_MIN);
        printf("signed short max: %d\n", SHRT_MAX);
        printf("unsigned short max: %d\n", USHRT_MAX);
        printf("INT\n");
        printf("signed int max: %d\n", INT_MAX);
        printf("unsigned int max: %u\n", UINT_MAX); 
        printf("signed int min: %d\n", INT_MIN);
        printf("LONG\n");
        printf("signed long max: %d\n", LONG_MAX);
        printf("unsigned long max: %u\n", ULONG_MAX);
        printf("signed long min: %d\n", LONG_MIN);
        printf("FLOAT\n");
        printf("signed float max: %e\n", FLT_MAX);
        printf("signed float min: %e\n", FLT_MIN);
        printf("DOUBLE\n");
        printf("signed double max: %e\n", DBL_MAX);
        printf("signed double min: %e\n", DBL_MIN);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: almost all of it worked except last 4 ones.

variables.c:23:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FLT_MAX'
  printf("signed float max: %e\n", FLT_MAX);
                                   ^
variables.c:24:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FLT_MIN'
  printf("signed float min: %e\n", FLT_MIN);
                                   ^
variables.c:26:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'DBL_MAX'
  printf("signed double max: %e\n", DBL_MAX);
                                    ^
variables.c:27:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'DBL_MIN'
  printf("signed double min: %e\n", DBL_MIN);

Comment: i think the names of double and float might be wrong?

Comment: @shunya I accidentally deleted the line `#include <float.h>` which I re-added in an edit. Hope it works now. :D

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood your qestion correctly.

You can take a look at `limits.h`, where you can find the sizes of integral types. Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).

> This header defines constants with the limits of fundamental integral
>   types for the specific system and compiler implementation used.

Answer (score 1):

Header `<limits.h>` provides these informations while `<stdint.h>` allows you to specify specific width integers:

```
INT_MAX
INT_MIN
int32_t value; // to have an integer of exactly 32 bits
```

Comment: I don't really understood this can you explain a little more if possible?

Comment: `INT_MAX`, `INT_MIN`, etc are macros which can tell you the ranges of data types on your current platform. Since an `int` can vary on different platforms, you have access, through `stdint.h` to types which guarantee a specific bit width (and thus a specific range)