# Why value of a variable of int type gets printed even if it does not lie in the range of int?

Tags: c, int, range

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a;
a=100000000;
printf("%d",a);
return(0);
}
```

//why value of a gets printed even if it larger than the range of int?

Comment: because range of int type in c is from -32767 to 32767

Comment: Those are only the smallest values. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717263/range-on-int-short-and-other-data-types-in-c-on-my-processor?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19466883/694733.

Comment: How can an `int` *not* fit into an `int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because range of int type in c is from -32767 to 32767

You have false assumptions there.

The range of type `int` is *not* fixed. An int is not necessarily 16 bits.

The C standard doesn't define a fixed range for `int`. It requires a conforming implementation supports *at least* the range -32767 to 32767 for `int`. But an implementation can support higher ranges. On most systems, an `int` is 32 bits wide.

So there's nothing unexpected in your output.
If you want to know the exact limits then you can use the macros `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` from `<limits.h>`.

Relevant C-FAQ: [How should I decide which integer type to use?](http://c-faq.com/decl/inttypes.html)

Answer (score 2):

That number fits on a 32 bit integer, which can hold up to ‭2,147,483,647‬ (signed).

Answer (score 1):

The size of "int" can vary across different CPU architectures.  If you want to be absolutely sure how large your integer is use:

```
int32_t a;  //this is a 32bit signed integer
uint16_t b; //16 bit unsigned integer
```

instead.

Comment: which header file is used for these @Wossname

Answer (score 0):

In C the size of an integer can be 2,4 or even 8 bytes. This can depend on the compiler that you are using and also on your system.

1. If your processor is 16-bit(of course this is ancient times) int will be 2   bytes.
2. For a 32-bit processor it will be mostly 4 bytes.
3. For a 64-bit processor it can even be 8 bytes.

The above was true for some extend for old compilers.

But this is not always the case. Cross compilation is required (among other things) to get around the host CPU's int being different from the int used on the target CPU. This can cause problems when porting code for use on multiple platforms. Most modern C compilers will allow the size of integers to be altered by the user.

Comment: This is not always the case.  Cross compilation is required (among other things) to get around the host CPU's int being different from the int used on the target CPU.  This can cause problems when porting code for use on multiple platforms.  Most modern C compilers will allow the sizes of integers to be altered by the user.